# Can iOS Apps contain Dynamic Libs?

Tags: ios, app-store, dylib

I have searched various sites and posts on here and feel the information regarding support for dylibs in iOS apps in the App Store is contradictory.

From what I've read it seems they are not supported directly but maybe as part of a dynamic framework? But dynamic frameworks are not recommended?

Can iOS Apps on the App Store contain dylibs at all?

Answer (score 0):

> From what I've read it seems they are not supported directly but maybe as part of a dynamic framework?

This is correct. We use libraries/shared objects in the form of frameworks.

> But dynamic frameworks are not recommended?

It is not recommended to have dozens of dynamic frameworks linked in an app, a few ones can be very useful. E.g. when you're sharing code between apps and app extensions.

> Can iOS Apps on the App Store contain dylibs at all?

Like I said before: Yes, in the form of a dynamic framework. You might be able to ship plain dylibs as well, but that would be an uncommon setup.